# Derivative of absolute value function

Tags: calculus, absolute-value

What is $f'(x)$ and $f''(x)$ of $f(x) = x^{1/3}\vert 4-x \vert$?

Do you use two cases or can it be solved a different way?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is easier to break it into two cases.
Another way is to use the derivative of $|x|$, which is $x/|x|$, but not defined at $x=0$,
and the second derivative which is $0$ but not defined at $x=0$.

Comment: But would this particular function have the same second derivative?

Comment: No, you need the product rule to find the first first derivative, and then $(f(x)g(x))''=f''(x)g(x)+2f'(x)g'(x)+f(x)g''(x)$ for the second derivative.  I prefer two cases, rather than this.

Answer (score 0):

Ask yourself: is there any point on this curve where it is not differentiable? If there is, then the derivative clearly has to be in two 'pieces', so you have to use two cases.

Comment: So if it cannot be differentiated at x=4, you would do cases where x>4 and x<4?

Comment: @Bryce Yes, exactly

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to do it by cases, but you can also use:

$\vert y \vert = (y^2)^{1/2}$